# jquery validation not working when triggered a submit link

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have download a jquery validation library from here  http://jqueryvalidation.org/
the validation or error messages works when submit button is clicked but i have a link which named as submit. I want to use that link as a submit but the problem is then validation library don't work. how can I customize the library.

here is my code on [jsfiddle](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

everything works fine when I use this

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

but i want to use the customize button not a submit button

```
 <a class="button black"  id="send-message">Send</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change the class for `input` tag by giving it the classes of `a` tag

```
<input class="button black" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

or write a code that will trigger your forms submit event on click

```
$("#send-message").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to init the a link via js and then init the validation class:

```
  <a class="button black"  id="send-message">Send</a>


  $("#send-message").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
          }
  });
```

more details on the validation class/plugin [JQ validate Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)